# Oracle SQL Developer update

Tags: software-update, sqldeveloper

I am trying to update my Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.2.20.

When I select components such as MySQL JDBC Driver or Perforce Extension then I am asked to log in using my Oracle Web Account.

This is when the problem starts. With my login and password there is absolutely no problem to log in using https://login.oracle.com. When I enter the same user and password in the SQL Developer dialog window then it seems to treat it as incorrect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the same issue on version 4.0.1.14 and looking at the network chat between SQL Developer and OTN website it seems the issue is not the password or authentication, but something else, as the website responds with a zip file that seems to be the driver that I asked for.

To me this looks like there is a (long-standing) bug in SQL Developer which makes it fail receiving the file sent by the server. As a workaround, you could download the driver from the website and the use `Tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers > Add Entry...` to install it.